# MySQL query won't execute - Class->Function->Form

Tags: php, mysql, execution

I have built a query (`` $query_q = "SELECT * FROM `table`;" ``) and am trying to execute it within a function.

```
public function read_from_table() {
    $query_q = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
    $query_a = mysql_query($query_q);
    while (mysql_fetch_array($query_a)) {
        echo "Did it!";
        //OR AS TRIED ANOTHER WAY
        return "Did it!";
    }
}
```

And called as such:

```
echo $classInstance->read_from_table();
//OR AS TRIED ANOTHER WAY
$classInstance->read_from_table();
```

Both the ways that the function and the class have been made have been tried in every conceivable way, and yet I still get no result.
I was getting the error that says the xecution time has exceeded the limit of 30 seconds, so I added the `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` (knowing this removes time limit altogether) to see if the query would execute at all, it has been running now for 30 minutes without a sign of life. Why is the query not executing?

**Additional comments:**

- I am aware that I am using the depreciated mysql_* functions, this is at client request and will be updated after the site has been made live and is complete to a point where I am ready to change it all to mysqli->* functions.
- The table that I am calling (it's name has been stripped and replaced with `` `table` ``) has only 9 rows in it, so this should not affect the execution time greatly (or will it?).
- I have had to strip all sensitive information from the function to satisfy the client and my employer. Please keep in mind that I cannot disclose and information that the client and my employer do not wish to disclose.

Comment: Are you sure a link was successfully opened by `mysql_connect()` before you do this?

Comment: As I see, there is no problem with this code. So if database connected, it should work. Maybe there are something in those removed information. If you just run this snippet, is it works? Also, use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file, to check, what could be the error.

Comment: What you can also do it put an `echo "step <number>";` after each line, or block of code, so you can see what the code is doing all that time. Perhaps it isn't the query at all?

Comment: Sorry for the late replies guys, thank you all for the help, the issue was the server (and with it my internet connection) went down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the internet and server had gone down.

This has since been sorted and is operational.

Thank you for help and support in this.

DigitalMediaMan

Answer (score 0):

try

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

if all ok, try run this query from console, look, how many times query will be performed

before this, kill old process in database(show processlist and kill pid)